# How to store more than 1 information (tags) per column when i extract the data?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, pipeline

I am currently testing my first spider with scrapy and everything seems to be working fine except for when i try to extract the data.

I set up a pipeline so that the items are saved and redirected to a database that can be read with sqlite3, there is multiple tags for each element but only the first one is kept when the data is exported.

I have 3 columns of data :

- title (1 data per row)
- author (one data per row)
- tags (multiple data per row).

The problem is that the column tag only shows the first tag that was captured

```
class QuotetutorialPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = _sqlite3.connect("myquotes.db")
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS quotes_tb""")
        self.curr.execute("""create table quotes_tb(
                        title text,
                        author text,
                        tag text
                        )""")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        print("Pipeline :" + item['title'][0])
        return item

    def store_db(self,item):
        self.curr.execute(""" insert into quotes_tb values (?,?,? )""", (
            item['title'][0],
            item['author'][0],
            item['tag']
        ))
```

I expect more than one element for the `item[tag]` but only the first one is saved.

Comment: Worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `item['tag']` right before `self.curr.execute`? What’s the value it has there? What’s the value that reaches the SQLite database?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose item['tag'] is a list. You have to decide how you want to store this.

```
# option 1: as json
import json
tags = json.dumps(item['tag'])  #  '["tag1", "tag2", ..]'

# option 2: as joined string
tags = '|'.join(item['tag']) # 'tag1|tag2'

# option 3: one row for each tag
for tag in item['tag']:
    self.curr.execute(""" insert into quotes_tb values (?,?,? )""", (
            item['title'][0],
            item['author'][0],
            tag
        ))
```